# Google Beacon - AppIntent Issue

Tags: android, google-nearby, google-beacon-platform, eddystone-url

I am trying to use beacons in my project. Facing some issue with it.

I am getting NearBy notification only for WebURL. I tried using it for AppIntent and FreeFormAppIntent using beacon dashboard but I am not getting the nearby notification from a beacon.

I had given schema as "Something" and package as "com.google.android.gms.nearby.messages.samples.hellobeacons" via beacon dashboard.

Please let me know the above AppIntent given data is correct!!
Please let me know what went wrong??

Answer (score 0):

You can find an example app intent used for Nearby Notifications here: https://developers.google.com/nearby/notifications/attachment_data_format

Also make sure that the app you want to launch can handle the intent you specify.